# Where to find an example of how the "switch" operator can be replaced by an array of functions?

Tags: c++, qt

I need a function, which can make one of some oparations:

```
typedef const bool (myClass::*DecoderFactory) (void);

DecoderFactory * decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory[1];
QVector<DecoderFactory> * decoderFunctions = new QVector<DecoderFactory>;

decoderFactory[0] = &MyClass::do0;

decoderFunctions->push_back(&MyClass::do0);
decoderFunctions->push_back(&MyClass::do1);
...


const bool someFunction(const short int code)
{
...
   decoderFactory[0] = decoderFunctions->value(code);
   if (!(this->*decoderFactory[0])()) return false;

   return true;

}


const bool do0()
{
   //do some
}

const bool do1()
{
   //do some
}

...
```

This is my current way, and certainly not the best. Can I make this easier? Specifically, how to do it without

```
DecoderFactory * decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory[1];
```

?  How I can do it not with array of one element, that is obvious like sh*tcode?

Comment: Why do you even have `DecoderFactory * decoderFactory = new DecoderFactory[1];`? Why is that needed?

Comment: The best explanation of function pointers for C and C++ I found so far, is this here: http://www.newty.de/fpt/fpt.html

Comment: "Addition: issue has been resolved" you should post it as an answer. I've edited it out of the question, you can still see what you wrote at http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/16495412/2.

Comment: I really wouldn't recommend deleting your questions - share what you learned with future readers as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use C++ containers and C++ function wrappers, it could be made easier:

```
struct MyClass
{
    typedef std::function<bool()> DecoderFactory;
    std::vector<DecoderFactory> decoderFunctions;

    MyClass() {
        decoderFunctions.push_back(std::bind(&MyClass::do0, this));
        decoderFunctions.push_back(std::bind(&MyClass::do1, this));
        //...
    }


    const bool someFunction(const short int code)
    {
       return decoderFunctions[code /*Did you mean CODE here instead of 0?;)*/]();
    }


    const bool do0()
    {
       //do some
    }

    const bool do1()
    {
       //do some
    }

};
```